# Porque só se pode ver a contagem de votos de dentro da pergunta?

Tags: debate, votação

Porque só podemos ver a contagem de votos de dentro da pergunta, não da listagem de perguntas?

Exibir contagem de votos faz uma trip no servidor (tanto quando se está dentro da pergunta quanto, se fosse possível, quando estivéssemos fora), então nem cabe o argumento que economiza trafego (e seria irrisório) . Porque não poder clicar na lista de perguntas e ver a contagem.

Parece-me que seria tão útil quanto, talvez mais. Uma pergunta tem 1 voto, mas se vemos que tem +4/-3, acho isso uma grande razão para ir ver e ajudar a definir. Talvez não fossemos conferir a pergunta se estivesse meramente +1/0.

Comment: Relacionado: [Mostrar os votos negativos e votos positivos, descrevendo melhor a realidade para os usuários](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1855/3117)

Comment: Se estiver com disposição, pode adaptar este script para fazer isso: [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](http://stackapps.com/q/3082/10590) . . . vai precisar de um `foreach` e decidir como injetar a informação dentro do design atual.

Comment: Acho uma jóia quando entro numa pergunta aparentemente inócua e descubro que o saldo é algo do tipo +8/-6 . . . Estou tentando achar alguma [*query* útil no SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=question+score) para listar umas dessas, mas nada...

Comment: @brasofilo o SEDE permite ver a contagem de votos? Porque se sim, potencialmente quebra o limite de 1000 pontos.

Comment: @RSinohara Confere de novo o comentário anterior ao SEDE... ;)

Comment: @brasofilo nossa... é... acho que não tinha carregado aqui... é, é isso. :D
Talvez o ideal seria uma marcação na pergunta quando esse 'empate' ocorre... ou uma fila de análise para isso. Nunca vai ter isso, mas seria legal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pelo mesmo motivo de eles estarem "escondidos" na página da pergunta: desempenho.

A contagem dos votos não é exibida por padrão, e só é acessível por quem tem [mais de 1000 pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), porque queremos que cada requisição seja o mais rápida o possível. Obter a contagem significa uma leitura a mais no banco de dados e dados a mais a serem transferidos.

Pode parecer besteira, mas quando você precisa atender algumas dezenas de milhões de requisições por mês, esse acesso a mais e dados a mais fazem diferença.

Se habilitássemos na página inicial, mesmo mantendo o privilégio, o mais provável é que todo mundo pedisse para ver a contagem o tempo todo... O que geraria carga extra da mesma maneira.

Comment: Entendo. Eu teria armazenado o valor na pergunta, em vez de ter que fazer a contagem toda vez... mas _who am I_... Imagino que o saldo não é contado toda vez, é armazenado... Mas isso responde à pergunta.

Comment: O *saldo* é armazenado no registro da pergunta, mas a contagem de up/down não.